# Kafka Streams topology initially dropping messages to intermediate topics

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We are leveraging Kafka Streams in a CDC setup streaming table level database changes into Kafka, aggregating them quite heavily and eventually streaming the result topics into OpenSearch.

I've noticed some strange behaviour when starting up the Kafka Streams applications after an initial database snapshot has been streamed into Kafka. Working on that snapshot data seems to produce message loss in case the intermediate topics utilized by the Streams topologies do not exist (and are auto-created on demand).

In fact I see e.g. about 3000 messages produced where I'd expect over 6000.

The topology (in that case) takes an input topic and does a series of 1:1 FK Left Joins to some other topics, so I'd expect the resulting topic to resemble the message count of the input topic. Specifically, I see message loss on one of the first internally created FK Join `-changelog` topics that carries on through the entire topology.

Assume this snippet:

```
            streamsBuilder //
                    .table( //
                            folderTopicName, //
                            Consumed.with( //
                                    folderKeySerde, //
                                    folderSerde)) //
                    .leftJoin( //
                            agencies, //
                            Folder::agencyIdValue, //
                            AggregateFolder::new, //
                            TableJoined.as("folder-to-agency"), //
                            Materializer //
                                    .<FolderId, AggregateFolder>named("folder-to-agency-materialized") //
                                    .withKeySerde(folderKeySerde) //
                                    .withValueSerde(aggregateFolderSerde)) //
                    .leftJoin( //
                            documents, //
...
```

The `folder-to-agency-materialized-changelog` topic shows significantly less messages then fed into the initial `folderTopicName` topic.

While starting up, the application logs lots of messages like these:

```
kstreams-folder-aggregator-folder-to-agency-subscription-response-topic=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION, ...
```

(For all kinds of intermediate topics)

In addition to that, when streaming another snapshot into Kafka while the Streams applications are already running (and thus all necessary intermediate topics already created) the resulting count of messages that have passed the topology resembles the expected count.

So, to sum this up: what might cause the mentioned initial message loss? Is the (automatic) intermediate topic creation somehow involved (although the logs show `WARN` level messages on this)?

Comment: Hard to say, as there are many moving parts and not enough information. About the `-changelog` topic, it might be related to caching (-> https://kafka.apache.org/10/documentation/streams/developer-guide/memory-mgmt#record-caches-in-the-dsl) -- In general, if you did not change default config, Kafka Streams should not lose messages. Yes, internal topics are created by Kafka Streams, but if they don't exist yet, it should not result in data loss.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Thanks for the hint. As far as I understand, caching works on key level (similar to compaction?), so this should not come into play here. All items streamed from the database table to the input topic feature distinct keys...

Comment: Yes, caching is key-based. Are you saying you have about 6000 unique keys, but you get only 3000 results, but expect 6000 (as it's a left join)?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant to say...

Comment: Can you somehow verify that all data is read (eg, you start from "earliest" on all input topics)? -- Might also be good to check if all records make it into each store by using IQ.

Comment: Hm, at least there's no configuration that says otherwise, so I suppose all input topics should start from 'earliest'. Is there a way to confirm that? - I'll try to check state stores then, as soon as I get back to work...

Comment: The logs would tell you if a consumer does a "seek (to earliest / latest)".